# how to not capture entire group with regex negative lookahead

Tags: php, regex, pcre

I have numbers like `1556278013708` or `34566` in text. Some of them followed by `"`, eg `1556278013708"`

I don't need numbers followed by `"`, so I tried `(\d+)(?!")`, but this still matches those numbers, just without the final digit, eg `155627801370`

How to make to not capture entire numbers with `"` right after?

Eg, `34567` - Match all of it

Eg, `34567"` - Match none of it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make the quantifier possessive instead - that way, once the engine matches all the digits, once it sees that the negative lookahead fails, the whole match will fail completely, rather than trying to backtrack:

```
\d++(?!")
```

https://regex101.com/r/6bIqdI/1

(note that if the *whole match* is those digits, there's no need for a capture group, just extract the whole match)

Answer (score 1):

*Alternatively*, placing a word boundary will also work:

```
\d+\b(?!")
```

Although using [possessive quantifier](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59710685/548225) is more efficient in PCRE but this regex can be used in other regex platforms such as Javascript or Python also where `++` is not supported.

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/6bIqdI/2)